# Why are clang/g++ in the "Developer-old" directory?

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, osx-lion

After updating my Mac to Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3 and XCode to version 4.3, I noticed that making a search for files such as clang or g++, the only results are in the "Developer-old" directory (I do not know if this happened on this occasion, or maybe even before).

Through the command line or IDEs I can still use the clang/g++ executables.

What does it mean? Am I using the executables in the renamed "Developer-old" directory?

Have I done something wrong during the update of my system, excluding development tools?

Thank you!

*Platform:*
MacBook Pro 2008
Lion 10.7.3
XCode 4.3

Comment: Maybe dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993835/gcc-command-line-on-mac-os-x-with-xcode-2-5

Comment: @MikeSamuel: it is not a duplication; we have different issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode 4.3 installs itself in /Applications/Xcode.app, and everything else is contained within that. If you need standalone command-line tools, you want to install the "Command Line Tools for Xcode" package, which you can find on [developer.apple.com/downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action).